# What temp files generated by latex can I delete without risk?

Tags: pdftex, compiling, external-files, auxiliary-files

My projectfolder consist of several 'real' files and is full of files I don't know.
There are some cleaning procedures which deletes specified endings after a run but I am not sure which filetypes I can delete without risk of some sort of data lost?

In my folder I have the endings:

```
- .aux
- .bbl
- .bcf
- syntex.gz
- .blg
- .out
- .pgs
- .toc
```

Can I just delete all of them or will my project is getting corrupt then?

EDIT.... and without receiving speedlost in a new compilation

Comment: You can delete all of them whenever needed, typically when you are finished with a project.  But since  some of them store things that are used on subsequent compilations (e.g. citations, cross-references, tables of contents etc.) it's generally advisable to keep them around unless they need to be deleted due to some error.  See [Will cruft from a previous compile ever change the final look of my document](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/82669) for more discussion (duplicate?).

Comment: You also can ask the compiler to run the compiler with the  switch, say, `--aux-directory=./TeXAux`, which will store most of the auxiliary files in a TeXAux subdirectory of the current directory (and  will create one if there is no such directory so far).

Comment: TexnicCenter has a Build->Clean Project option which will delete all the temp files for you.