# Understanding all output files when compiling a LaTeX document

Tags: output

I've been using MiKTeX for a while, but I haven't really understood what all the output files are. I'm using pdflatex and I've just started using biber for bibliography. When I compile a .tex file I get 9 output files. These 2 I understand:

- .pdf
- .log

But I didn't really grasp what is the function of these 7:

- .synctex.gz
- .aux
- .bbl
- .bcf
- .blg
- .out
- .run
- .xml

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448360/what-temp-files-generated-by-latex-can-i-delete-without-risk and the related questions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- `.synctex.gz`: Synctex stores a correspondence between the output PDF and the `.tex` source. Some editors use it to show your cursor position in the PDF or PDF scroll position in the `.tex` source. See [What exactly is SyncTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118489/242407)
- `.aux`: Open it in a text editor, you'll see this file is used mostly for reference information.

  For example, if you use `\ref{}` but the corresponding `\label{}` is only later in the document, LaTeX has not seen it, and won't look ahead. Instead, each time there is a `\label{}`, a command gets written to the `.aux` file. Next time you compile your `.tex`, that `.aux` is inputted right before the document gets started, and the command you had written to it then registers the value for `\ref{}`.
- `.toc` (bonus): If you use `\tableofcontents`, this will create a `.toc` file as well, because just as for the `.aux` file: there is no looking ahead. The `.toc` records a `\contentsline` for each section encountered. Upon use of `\tableofcontents`, this file is inputted, and each `\contentsline` constitutes a line in the contents table.
- `.bbl`: Is outputted by biber (or bibtex), contains the prepared data to be used by biblatex (or natbib).
- `.bcf`: Is outputted by biblatex (or natbib), contains which citations biber (or bibtex) should prepare.
- `.blg`: The log file of biber (or bibtex).
- `.out`: Used by `hyperref` to store a list of PDF bookmarks. Note how the information can differ from that in `.toc`. For example when adding `\pdfbookmark` without a corresponding one for the TOC, or when using `\texorpdfstring`. This latter one allows for a different title in the PDF toc. See the following example:

  ```
  \section[\texorpdfstring{I'm in document toc!}{I'm in PDF toc!}]{I'm in \TeX!}
  \section{I'm in \texorpdfstring{\TeX{} or toc! $\cos(\theta)$}{PDF toc! cos(\texttheta)}}
  ```

  You see `\texorpdfstring` string can be used to provide a fallback for math, which can't be typeset in a PDF toc. I'm using the package `\textgreek` here.
- `.run.xml`: The header of this file contains `"logreq request file"`. According to CTAN, this package logs a couple of useful messages, like `"please rerun LaTeX"`. (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/logreq)

Comment: Nice summary.  Would add that `.blg` is also the name of the BibTeX log file.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yep, good catch

Comment: @Teepeemm yes it does. TOC is generator only from `.toc`. As soon as you use `\tableofcontents` it setups a file handle to write to a `.toc`-file, or similar for `\tableoffigures`. As he didn't mention a `.toc`-extension, and the `.aux`-system is a bit interwoven with the `.toc` files and such, I thought I would give this example anyway

Comment: @Teepeemm in fact, the reason why there are separate files for each table of ..., is because they are inputted when you use `\tableof...`. The `aux` file is read at document load, and generates these files I think, and does other things like setting reference numbers

Comment: @Teepeemm I've updated my answer to disambiguate between the `.toc` and `.aux`. I had kind of hastely written my answer.